# How to prove this proposition that has to do with elements and equivalence relations

Tags: equivalence-relations

Every element $z$ in $X$ is in exactly one equivalence class. Not sure how to prove this.

I proved that every element $z$ in $X$ is in some equivalence class by using the definition of $[x]$. How would I prove that it is in exactly one equivalence class?

Comment: Prove that if two classes intersect, then they are equal.

Comment: Hint: suppose that $z$ is in two equivalence classes, and deduce that they must actually be the same equivalence class.

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is in two different equivalence class then neither is empty.

For any $y$ in the first equivalence class then $y \equiv x$, and for any $z$ in the second equivalence class then $x \equiv y$.  So by the transitivity of equivalence $y \equiv z$ implying that $y$ is in the second equivalence class and  $z$ is in the first equivalence class.  So the two equivalence classes have the same members and are not different, contradicting the assumption.

So $x$ is not in more than one equivalence class.

But it is in at least one, the equivalence class of things equivalent to $x$.